# Batch Processing on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, spring-batch, batch-processing

Anyone here have experience about batch processing (e.g. spring batch) on kubernetes ? Is it good idea ? How to prevent batch processing process same data if we use kubernetes auto scaling feature ? Thank you.

Comment: I personally looked into using Kubernetes for batch processing, and decided not to do it because of the auto-scaling problem you mention. I have batch processes that typically run 1-4 hours. Technically I could run them in Kubernetes, but my pods would end up repeating themselves every time the cluster scaled down. Technically I might be able to checkpoint when I receive a SIGTERM, but it started to seem like too much work compared with just spinning up individual VMs and watching their progress. Overall, Kubernetes doesn't seem designed for this use-case.

Comment: Here's a longer article that somebody wrote on the topic. Bottom line, Kubernetes might be a great choice for some needs, and a bad choice for others. https://www.ben-morris.com/do-you-really-need-kubernetes/

Comment: It's also worth noting that Google had a beta program for batch processing in GKE but then deprecated it: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/batch

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Anyone here have experience about batch processing (e.g. spring batch) on kubernetes ? Is it good idea ?

For Spring Batch, we (the Spring Batch team) do have some experience on the matter which we share in the following talks:

- [Cloud Native Batch Processing on Kubernetes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1NZVwv1cmMc), by Michael Minella
- [Spring Batch on Kubernetes](https://speakerdeck.com/benas/spring-batch-kubernetes), by me.

Running batch jobs on kubernetes can be tricky:

- pods may be re-scheduled by k8s on different nodes in the middle of processing
- cron jobs might be triggered [twice](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#cron-job-limitations)
- etc

This requires additional non-trivial work on the developer's side to make sure the batch application is fault-tolerant (resilient to node failure, pod re-scheduling, etc) and safe against duplicate job execution in a clustered environment.

Spring Batch takes care of this additional work for you and can be a good choice to run batch workloads on k8s for several reasons:

- **Cost efficiency:** Spring Batch jobs maintain their state in an external database, which makes it possible to restart them **from the last save point** in case of job/node failure or pod re-scheduling
- **Robustness:** Safe against duplicate job executions thanks to a centralized job repository
- **Fault-tolerance:** Retry/Skip failed items in case of transient errors like a call to a web service that might be temporarily down or being re-scheduled in a cloud environment

I wrote a blog post in which I explain all these aspects in details with code examples. You can find it here: [Spring Batch on Kubernetes: Efficient batch processing at scale](https://spring.io/blog/2021/01/27/spring-batch-on-kubernetes-efficient-batch-processing-at-scale)

> How to prevent batch processing process same data if we use kubernetes auto scaling feature ?

Making each job process a different data set is the way to go (a job per file for example). But there are different patterns that you might be interested in, see [Job Patterns](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#job-patterns) from k8s docs.